# Why Jquery is not working for CssClass property of LinkButton in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have this code:

jquery:

```
$(".clr").click(function () {
            $(".clr").each(function () {
                $(this).parents("li").css("background", "#000")
            })
            var color1 = "#f8ac00";
            $(this).parents("li").css("background", color1);
        });
```

ASP.NET:

```
 <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">

                    <li class="topfirst">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_dashbd" CssClass="clr" Height="18" Width="100" runat="server">Dashboard</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="topmenu">

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_events" CssClass="clr" Height="18" Width="100" runat="server">Events</asp:LinkButton>

                    </li>
                    <li class="topmenu">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_myaccount" CssClass="clr" Height="18" Width="100" runat="server">My Account</asp:LinkButton>


                    </li>


                    <li class="toplast">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_abtus" CssClass="clr" Height="18" Width="100" runat="server">About Us</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Image reference:
[image: Menu]

I have defined CssClass property of LinkButton, mapping it to Jquery class. But on click, this code is not working. I don't know why? Please help me.

Comment: As a suggestion, use `closest` instead of `parents` if you expect a single, or first, match. You can also simplify the first part to just `$("li:has(.clr)").css("background", "#000")`

Comment: You are also using the selector $(".clr") twice. you can define it in an external variable and use it like this: var buttons = $(".clr")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from not knowing what behavior you are getting from the button clicks (page postback?), these are just my suggestions put together for you to try.

Please try the following as a test:

```
   $(".clr").click(function (e) {
        // Stop the click behavior for now (postback?)
        e.preventDefault();

        // Turn off all the LIs
        $("li:has(.clr)").css("background", "#000");

        // Turn on the closest LI to the clicked linkButton
        var color1 = "#f8ac00";
        $(this).closest("li").css("background", color1);
    })
```

Comment: @Manoj Maximum: Was it just the buttons reloading the page as I assumed?

Comment: actually nope. It isn't reloading the page. My code doesn't changed the background color of "li". Yours did it. THANK YOU

Comment: That is weird... I am now very curious what was wrong with your code (as it should have worked). Can you post a JSFIddle with the HTML from a save-as in a browser (not the source) so I can test it?

Comment: I am new to Jsfiddle. Let me take sometime

Comment: Just `copy`, `paste`, `save`... Use the HTML window as a text editor :)